# INSERT Mysql Micro Focus Cobol error 1064 if host variables used

Tags: mysql, cobol

Getting error `-1064` while inserting into table using host variables. Works find if hard coded values used instead of host variables.

Tried the same sql statement using hardcoded values as well as host variables. Changed picture clauses, used indicator variables etc for host variables but nothing works.

Host variables declared:

```
   EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.
   01 hfname  pic x(45).
   01 hlname  pic x(45).
   01 hdeptid pic S9(09) comp-4.
       EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.
```

Code snippet below:

```
       EXEC SQL
           INSERT INTO employee (Fname, Lname, DeptId)
           VALUES ("abc", "def", 005)
       END-EXEC
       if sqlcode not = 0
           display sqlcode
           display sqlerrmc
           stop run
       end-if.
```

The above code works fine. The same code with variables instead of hard coded values as below gives the mentioned error:

```
       EXEC SQL
           INSERT INTO employee (Fname, Lname, DeptId)
           VALUES (:hfname, :hlname, :hdeptid)
       END-EXEC

       if sqlcode not = 0
           display sqlcode
           display sqlerrmc
           stop run
       end-if.
```

Not able to figure out why using host variables does not work. I have tried changing field lengths etc but nothing works. used simple pic 9(4) instead of s9(09) comp but does not work. Googled quite a bit but not many discussions on mysql cobol. Thanks for any help you can provide.